# eclipse debugger showing false info?

Tags: eclipse, debugging

Im trying to do some debugging on Eclipse but it seems like the debugger is lying to me. I have a `Map<String, NormalizedFunction>` called functions. When I hit my breakpoint the variable functions is visible. When I select it from the variables view it shows "`{getX()=[]int getX()}`", which is correct. Clearly this map has a key and a value. However, when I open up the functions variable and select `keyset` or `values` eclipse says its null. How can this be if it clearly shows that there was a key and a value, and the code runs correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debugger is not lying. You're assuming that all the keys of the map should be stored in the private `keySet` field of the HashMap. But this is not the case. This variable is lazily populated when the `keySet()` method is called. Just look at the method implementation.

If you want to know something about your map, use its documented, specified API: use the *Display* view, type `functions.keySet()`, right-click and choose "Evaluate", and then you'll really get the key set of the map.